# Web scraping for hidden content

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the price data from this website: https://fuelkaki.sg/home

However, the data does not appear to be in the HTML code of the page. Upon inspecting, the data seems to be nested in the  tag, for instance under Caltex for the retailer name, and similarly under multiple nested tags for the price data, which I am unable to scrape with the following code (there are no results to be found).

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://fuelkaki.sg/home'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find('div', class_='fuel-name')
```

Comment: Explore selenium to scrape hidden data. Beautiful soup is only limited to what the html contents.

Answer (score 0):

The table is behind `JS` (JavaScript) so `BeautifulSoup` won't see it.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = "https://fuelkaki.sg/home"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="table"]')
print(element.text)
driver.close()
```

Output:

```
Diesel
92
95
98
Others
(V-Power, etc)
Caltex
3‬‬‬‬‬‬0‬‬‬‬‬‬ ‬‬‬‬‬‬S‬‬‬‬‬‬e‬‬‬‬‬‬p‬‬‬‬‬‬t‬‬‬‬‬‬e‬‬‬‬‬‬m‬‬‬‬‬‬b‬‬‬‬‬‬e‬‬‬‬‬‬r‬‬‬‬‬‬ ‬‬‬‬‬‬2‬‬‬‬‬‬0‬‬‬‬‬‬2‬‬‬‬‬‬0‬‬‬‬‬‬,‬‬‬‬‬‬ ‬‬‬‬‬‬0‬‬‬‬‬‬2‬‬‬‬‬‬:‬‬‬‬‬‬0‬‬‬‬‬‬5‬‬‬‬‬‬p‬‬‬‬‬‬m
S$ 1‬‬‬‬.‬‬‬‬7‬‬‬‬3
S$ 2‬‬‬.‬‬‬0‬‬‬2
S$ 2‬‬‬.‬‬‬0‬‬‬6
N.A.
S$ 2‬‬‬‬‬‬.‬‬‬‬‬‬6‬‬‬‬‬‬1
and so on...
```

EDIT:

If you want the table in a `Dataframe` try this:

```
import time

import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = "https://fuelkaki.sg/home"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser").select_one(".table")

df = pd.read_html(str(soup))
df = pd.concat(df).rename(columns={"Unnamed: 0": ""})
df.to_csv("fuel_data.csv", index=False)
driver.close()
```

Outputs a `.csv` file with the table's data:

[image]